# C# WPF Databinding of control properties in a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Could someone please explain why the databinding in the following example isn't working and what I need to do to make it work? I've searched all day for similar examples and read many articles about databinding but I couldn't find an explanation for this.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ListView Name="ListView1" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Col1" Width="150">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Name="TextBox1" Text="blablabla" Width="150"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>

                <GridViewColumn Header="Col2" Width="150">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Name="TextBox2" Text="{Binding ElementName=TextBox1, Path=Text}" Width="150"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListViewItem>test</ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

The error is:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=TextBox1'. BindingExpression:Path=Text; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBox' (Name='TextBox2'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what are you trying to do with this code? IsChecked in TextBox? you invented?

Comment: You can't create an ElementName binding to UI elements in a different NameScope. Create a proper ViewModel and all your problems will magically disappear.

Comment: Textbox1 is part of a Datatemplate and thus cannot be referenced by name in a different Datatemplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As HighCore and kmacdonald said, this is a scope problem. DataTemplate inner elements cannot be accessed from outside. MVVM is the solution, so you should put your shared text on a ViewModel.

**Window**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListView Name="ListView1" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Col1" Width="150">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Name="TextBox1" Text="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="150"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn Header="Col2" Width="150">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Name="TextBox2" Text="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True" Width="150"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <ListViewItem Content="{Binding}"/>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Window's code behind**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private String text;

    public String Text
    {
        get
        {
            return this.text;
        }
        set
        {
            this.text = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Text");
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```